# Error 001143 and Error 99999 when using Locate Features Along Routes in ArcGIS10.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, route, error-999999, error-001143

Oddly, what I need to do has worked for about half of my data but not the rest.

I'm trying to use the Locate Features Along Routes tool in ArcGIS10.1. I have a smaller polyline layer as the input and another larger polyline routes layer as the input routes layer. Where they occupy the same geographic space, the layers overlap exactly. There is an attribute called "reach code" in both feature classes and they match, this tool will allow me to see "to" and "from" on the input layer when done. I was able to execute it once so I know it works.

Basically, I've got four large watersheds that I'd like to do this for. The tool ran smoothly for the first one but will not work for the other three. There should not be substantial differences between these datasets. I've obtained the data straight from the USGS NHD website so it is unaltered with fields and properties identical among watersheds. There was a problem at first and the tool did not work until I saved the output events table to the desktop instead of the network or the hard drive.

I have disabled Background Processing since I thought that was the issue. When Background Processing is disabled I get the 99999 error. When it is enabled I get the 001143 error, that says I should turn off background processing. I'm stuck in a cyclic zone of zero productivity. Hoping some of the experts out there can shed some light!

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question almost two weeks later.....the issue is the location of source data on a network rather than on the hard drive of the machine. Moved the data to the hard drive and everything has worked fine

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same error but all the files were local on my hard disk.  It turns out that at some point part of the workspace (including the geodatabase) had been marked as read-only.  This meant that I couldn't process anything that output to this database.  Fixing the file permissions fixed the issue.